# Why does the Code only show 'array'

Tags: php

Hello Guys I try to short the content of a post in a preview page. I have tried out the code and it doesn't work. It shows only an 'array' as text. Is this echo wrong or any other failures?

```
$word=Hello World;


$words = str_word_count($word, 1,'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ');
$len = min(50, count($words));
$first_fifty = array_slice($words, 0, $len);
echo $first_fifty;
```

Thanks for Help...

Comment: `Hello World` that and if it's your real code and being unquoted, is a constant; did you define it first?

Comment: `array_slice` returns an array, you can't echo an array directly.  Loop it or `implode` it and echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. `$word=Hello World;` should be `$word='Hello World';`
2. You are echoing an array; do `print_r ($first_fifty);` instead;

   All the code:

   `<?php
     $word='Hello World';
     $words = str_word_count($word, 1,'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ');
     $len = min(50, count($words));
     $first_fifty = array_slice($words, 0, $len);
     print_r ($first_fifty);
   ?>`

You can echo:

```
<?php
  echo $first_fifty[0] . ' ' . $first_fifty[1];
?>
```

Comment: @RicoRichterYou are welcome any time.